# How to color a button differently when it's selected HTML

Tags: html, user-interface, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to make a website that has buttons. I'm trying to make it so that the button highlights when you click on it but I don't know which HTML page name to put for this to work.

```
<div class="topnav">
      <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="builds.html">Builds</a>
</div>
```

Right now it says home but I want to make that so it switches to whichever page it's on. Right now
it shows the Home being highlighted even though I'm on the Builds page
[image]

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: Consider using a framework like Bootstrap.  In any case (if you haven't already done so), definitely familiarize yourself with HTML5,  CSS3 and Javascript first.  In this simple instance, however, it sounds like 1) you've shown us a snippet from one page: "index.html" (your "Home" page). 2) You have a second, "Build" page (build.html).  3) If so, just copy/paste the same elements into build.html, only change the text: `<a class="active" href="builds.html">Builds</a>`

Comment: I tried switching it to builds.html on the Builds page but switches it so that the highlighted box's text is Build instead of Home but the highlight doesn't change. I'm trying to get the highlight to change to the Build box, is there any way to do this? Thanks

Comment: @walker38552 you're trying to change the html of the *home* button. You want to change the *builds* button on the builds page so that it is *class="active"* as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do this automatically in plain html (plus, if you could, you'd have to do just as much manual work to make it automatic), but you can (as the comment states) do it manually:

Home:

```
<div class="topnav">
      <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="builds.html">Builds</a>
</div>
```

Builds:

```
<div class="topnav">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a class="active" href="builds.html">Builds</a>
</div>
```